# how to convert dataframe output from databricks to csv in ADF without using copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, adx

I have parquet files in ADLS and have to convert them to dataframe then covert them again to csv file type then append the files in ADX...

I'm able to convert all the parquet files to dataframes and I'm trying to use ADF to convert the each outout(dataframe to csv file type and append it using adx activity.

I can't use df.write.csv('name.csv') or df.toPandas().to_csv('name'), because I don't have write permission to the ADLS storage.
I'm also not allowed to use copy activity in ADF to convert files.

Is there any solution to do this in ADF?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @MMV it is not possible to reproduce as per above scenario .Please get enough permission to the ADLS storage.

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi! I think we could write csv files into the ADLS storage but is it possible to append files in ADX without using copy activity in ADF?